# How can I test if a list contains another list with particular items in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists and want to check if it already contains a list with particular items.

Everything should be clear from this example:

```
list = [[1,2],[3,4],[4,5],[6,7]]
for test in [[1,1],[1,2],[2,1]]:
  if test in list:
    print True
  else:
    print False

#Expected:
#        False
#        True
#        True

#Reality:
#        False
#        True
#        False
```

Is there a function that compares the items of the list regardless how they are sorted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching values of a list in another List using Python ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695452/searching-values-of-a-list-in-another-list-using-python)

Comment: for test in ...: print sorted(test) in list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to use is a set:
`set([1,2]) == set([2,1])`
returns True.

So

```
list = [set([1,2]),set([3,4]),set([4,5]),set([6,7])]
set([2,1]) in list
```

also returns True.

Comment: By the way, in Python3--something perhaps a future generation will actually be able to use--you can say `[{1,2}, {3,4}, {4,5}, {6,7}]`.

Answer (score 5):

If they're really sets, use the set type

```
# This returns True 
set([2,1]) <= set([1,2,3])
```

`<=` means 'is a subset of' when dealing with sets. For more see the [operations on set types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get [1,2] = [2,1] you should not use list. Set is the correct type. In list, the order of the components matter, in set they don't. That's why you don't get 'False True True'.