# how to search and find multiple string from a predifined list to another list in python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm quite new to python. I'm looking for a solution for search a list and finding the data.

I googled but couldnt find anything specific to my code. i tried find, in ,set it doesnt seem to work.

I'm trying to search and match mutiple string  in a predifined list in another list (it's actually a resoponse from a serial port )

This is my code

```
responsetocheck = "replyid, ID,ID,transmitid"

datafromport= "replyid, ID, timestamp,sometherinfo,someotherinfo1,ID,transmitid"
```

I have to compare and find the entire responsetocheck and return true if all the strings are matching with the responsetocheck.

I tried these below given options

```
if (responsetocheck  in datafromport)  # it's not finding the data

if (set(responsetocheck) <= set(datafromport) )  # returns True even if 2- 3 values
                                                 # are matching - the reverse way of
                                                 # checking just returns true though
                                                 # if just one matches.

responsetocheck[0] in datafromport [0] # and the respective index's : getting 
                                       # out of range error

 if all(word in data for word in response) # doesnt seem to work as well
```

The options might have some syntax error. I've listed down just for letting you know of the options that I had used.

Comment: could you indent your code?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You haven't shown any _lists_ of strings. `responsetocheck` is a single string, as well as `datafromport`. What exactly is the condition you want to test on these strings?

Comment: sorry for that, its just a list and and my intention is to compare two list but its not one to one match still i need to find all the values in response.

Comment: sorry for that, its just a list and and my intention is to compare two list but its not one to one match still i need to find all the values in response.  The Scenario is i'm reading a serial data via serial port which transmits some data for every one minute and data list gets updated whenever the serial port sends the message  and i need to check every time  whether  it matches all the contents with my predefined response and  if it matches with the data , then i should return that the receiver has found the data. but the predifined response list is not one to one match with the data list .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you have the varibles responsetocheck and datafrom ports that both contains a string representing a comma separated list of words that you want to check. In that case you need to make your strings into python lists before doing the comparison. Like this:

```
responsetocheck = responsetocheck.replace(' ','').split(',')
datafromport = datafromport.replace(' ', '').split(',')
```

You now have two lists that look like this:

```
['replyid', 'ID', 'ID', 'transmitid'] #responsetocheck
['replyid', 'ID', 'timestamp', 'sometherinfo', 'someotherinfo1', 'ID', 'transmitid'] # datafromport
```

Then you have to iterate through each word in the responsetocheck list and check if it is found in the datafromport list. The following code should give you the results you want (If I've understood you correctly):

```
all(s in datafromport for s in responsetocheck)
```

Comment: I think the OP might be looking for the list of matching elements, in which case the `all()` would just be a `[...]` list comphrehension. You could also use set/union: `list( set(lista) & set(listb) )`

Comment: Hi espensb , Thanks a lot for your response, i tried as you suggested ;but it doesnt seem to work either . I'm getting an error as          "  'list object has no attribute 'replace'  "

Comment: sorry i should have mention that , its actually a list of one string, i could split the list .But somehow i couldnt compare them and filter the right data. though i'm getting the right data from the serial port

Comment: So the value of 'datafromport' is actually ["replyid, ID, timestamp,sometherinfo,someotherinfo1,ID,transmitid"]? In that case you can just use 'datafromport = datafromport[0]' before doing what I described above. Anyways, I suggest you give some examples of exactly what the values of 'datafromport' and 'responsetocheck' look like.

Comment: Hi , the code goes like this                                    responsecheck = "$VR,1,2,Txstationdata"                         datafromport = "$VR,1,12454.789,09,00,2,TxStationdata"                 the data port keeps updating whenever it received data from serial port       like datafromport= "$VR,1,12457.890,09,00,rangepule,98,00" , the list index keeps changing for everyinoput that it receives , so index option didnt work as well

Comment: I have found a similar query in [Searching values of list in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695452/searching-values-of-a-list-in-another-list-using-python) and my problem is fixed now , thankyou all for your response